# TypeError: 'encoding' while installing CairoSVG and WeazyPrint on Python 2.7

Tags: python

While installing CairoSVG and WeazyPrint on a Dockerfile I keep getting this TypeError:

```
Collecting WeasyPrint
  Downloading WeasyPrint-0.34.tar.gz (391kB)
Collecting cairosvg
  Downloading CairoSVG-2.0.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-pSKp0y/cairosvg/setup.py", line 24, in <module>
        with open(init_path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fd:
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some [research](https://github.com/Kozea/CairoSVG/issues/129), I Found that CairoSVG-2.x is for Python 3+. Problem was solved when I installed 1.x version:

```
pip install cairosvg==1.0.22
```

Comment: This worked for me too. I was getting mad about why it worked in Python 3 and not Python 2 and was lucky to find this thread. Thanks for posting the answer.